# Sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Find the radius of convergence and the sum of power series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

Radius of convergence is $R=1$, and the interval of convergence is $-1<x<1$.

I am having trouble in finding the sum.

Here is what I have tried.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+1)x^{2n+1}\int_0^1t^{2n}dt=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+1)x^{2n+1}t^{2n}\right)dt$$

$$=x\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+1)(xt)^{2n}\right)dt$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+1)(xt)^{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(xt)^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(xt)^{2n}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(xt)^{2n}=\frac{(xt)^2}{1-(xt)^2}$$

How to find the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(xt)^{2n}?$$

**EDIT:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2(2n+1)}\right)'$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{2n}\int_0^1t^{2n}dt=\frac{1}{2}x^2\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(xt)^{2n}\right)dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x^2\int_0^1\frac{(xt)^2}{1-(xt)^2}=\frac{1}{2}x^4\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{1-(xt)^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x^4\cdot\frac{1}{x^3}(-x-\frac{1}{2}\ln|x-1|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+1|)\Rightarrow$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}x\left(-x-\frac{1}{2}\ln|x-1|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+1|\right)\Rightarrow$$
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2(2n+1)}\right)'=-x-\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln|x-1|+\frac{x}{x-1}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln|x+1|+\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\Rightarrow$$

Finally,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=-x-\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln|x-1|+\frac{x}{x-1}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln|x+1|+\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$

**Question:** Is this correct?

Comment: You have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na^n = \frac{a}{(a-1)^2}$ if $|a|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is good. Here's another way to do it.

Let,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Clearly we have,

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}-1$$

It follows,

$$f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)-x$$

Now let,

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Clearly we have,

$$2g(x)+f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n+1}$$

$$2g(x)+\tanh^{-1}(x)-x=\frac{x}{1-x^2}-x$$

From which we get,

$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2-2x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{-1}(x)$$

We are interested in $g(x)+f(x)$ this is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{-1}(x)+\frac{x}{2-2x^2}-x$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\ln (x+1)-\frac{1}{4}\ln (1-x)+\frac{x}{2-2x^2}-x$$

**Edit**

Note another way:

Assume $|x|<1$ and $|t|<1$.

$$\int_{0}^{x} t^{2n} dt=\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

So that

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

$$=\int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t^{2n} dt$$

$$=\int_{0}^{x} \left(\frac{1}{1-t^2}-1 \right) dt $$

$$=\text{tanh}^{-1}(x)-x$$

It also follows that,

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}xf(x)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}x\text{tanh}^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$

So this way works too. Just continue with your work or the previous solution.

Comment: In my edited post, after $t$ substitution, I have set the limits of integration from $0$ to $1$, but I don't know if that is correct. If it is correct, then why? Is it because the interval of convergence is $-1<x<1$, so we integrate across radius $R$ from $0$ to $1$? Also, in cases where we don't have a substitution, then the integration interval is from $0$ to $x$. Is that correct?

Comment: For example, if we want to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ by using integration, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^x x^{n-1}dx=...=-\ln|1-x|,\forall |x|<1$. Here, the interval of integration is $0<x<x$. Why isn't it $0<x<1$ like in the original problem? My question is how to choose the interval of integration?

Comment: Because the sum converges for $|x|<1$ it makes sense to integrate $t$ over the interval $[0,1)$. That way everything you wrote down converges and makes sense together, such as when you switched the sum and the integral. If the sum hadn't converged, it wouldn't had made sense to do that. But it does converge as we have $|tx|<(1)(1)$ assuming we let $x \in (-1,1)$ and $t \in [0,1)$. I don't understand your last sentence can you please elaborate.

Comment: What you wrote down doesn't make sense, you can't have your integration variable in your bounds. Also you need to make sure that everything perfectly exists before going further with the algebra.

Comment: How would you evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ with integration? What would be integration limits?

Comment: Assume $|x|<1$. We have $\int_{0}^{x} u^{n-1} du$ exists. Also assume $|u|<1$. Then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} u^{n-1} du=\int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u^{n-1} du$. Given the restrictions everything I right makes sense because everything converges. @user_99

Comment: @ Ahmed S. Attaalla, That is exactly what I am confused with. You have also set the limits of integration from $0$ to $x$. If you do it in my edited post of the original problem, then the result is wrong. I don't understand when limits go from $0$ to $x$, and when from $0$ to $1$. Could you please explain that?

Comment: I don't no where you went wrong without showing the work, it works so long as everything makes sense. Please see my edit where I show it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

$$\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^{2n}$$

And now use the geometric series

$$\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$$

$$\frac d{dr}\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)r^n$$

Answer (score 1):

> *How to find the sum of  $\displaystyle \,\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(xt)^{2n}\,?$*

One may start with the standard *finite* evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag1
$$ then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ and *by making* $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, *using $|x|<1$*, *multiplying* by $x$, gives

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},\qquad |x|<1. \tag3
> $$

Comment: But what is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{2n}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

For the converge use Ratio Test.

$$2S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n+1+1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{2n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

The first sum is clearly an Infinite Geometric Series.

Now for the second part $$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$